# How to remove server header from nginx response in elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to remove the server header (`server: nginx/1.20.0`) from elastic beanstalk response. I have added `00_server.conf` to `.platform/nginx/conf.d/` in the source bundle with the following configuration

```
server {
    server_tokens off;
}
```

I am expecting this would extend the Elastic Beanstalk default nginx configuration as mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) and at least remove the version from the server header. But this is not working.

I need help with the following things:

1. How do I extend the default configuration so that I can remove the server version?
2. How do I remove the complete header?

I have looked at the similar questions on stackoverflow but they don't seem to help.

**Update**:
Issue 1 is resolved. `server_tokens` need to be inside the http context. Updating the above configuration to

```
server_tokens off;
```

fixed the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 0):

To remove the `Server` header *completely* you have [many options](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx/how-to-remove-the-server-header-in-nginx), of which most prominent would be using [`ngx_security_headers`](https://github.com/GetPageSpeed/ngx_security_headers) module:

```
hide_server_tokens on;
```

Comment: How can you enable custom modules to nginx in AWS Elastic Beanstalk as the question requested?